# two way binding of iterable in ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6

I am using `ngFor` to create a list of items containing clickable icons.
 When I click on an icon, it calls a function to update a variable in the backend and when successful, I'd like the icon to change color.

How can I "two-way" bind the iteratable variable `obj` so that when I modify it in the controller it reflects in the template ?

Template:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let obj of contactList | separator  " 
(click)="show_memories(obj.key, obj.bookName)" class="task-snoozed" no-lines>
    <button ion-button icon-only clear 
   (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); sendChangeState(obj, 'toBe', obj.toBeAlerted)">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft-circle" size="large" 
        [color]="obj.toBeAlerted ? 'primary' : 'gray-light'"></ion-icon>
    </button>

</ion-item>
```

Controller:

```
sendChangeState(contact:any, alertType:string, bool:boolean){

    this.firestoreService.changeAlertState(this.userId, contact.key, alertType, bool)
    .then(() => {
        //update the icon color here:
        contact.toBeAlerted = !contact.toBeAlerted; 
    });     
}
```

**EDIT**
contactList is an object like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you checked if two-way binding is working perfectly or not. Put interpolation in the template to check if `obj.toBeAlerted` is changing or not.

Comment: obj is the iterative variable so I am wondering how to modify each obj specifically from the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let obj of contactList | separator; index as i;" (click)="show_memories(obj.key, obj.bookName)" class="task-snoozed" no-lines>

    <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); sendChangeState(obj, 'toBe', !obj.toBeAlerted)">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft-circle" size="large" [color]="contactList[obj.key].toBeAlerted ? 'primary' : 'gray-light'"></ion-icon>
    </button>

</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 5):

When you bind single CSS property using property binding always use
style.property-name as follows:

Use [style.color] instead of [color]

Replace below line

`[color]="obj.toBeAlerted ? 'primary' : 'gray-light'"`

with

`[style.color]="obj.toBeAlerted ? 'primary' : 'gray-light'"`

You can also use ngStyle to apply css conditionally as follows

```
[ngStyle]="{'color': "obj.toBeAlerted ? 'primary' : 'gray-light'"}"
```

Comment: yes but my question is how to modify obj.toBeAlerted in the controller ?

Comment: send the whole object to Show_memories method then you can get the array element position. using position you can modify obj.toBeAlerted property  like (click)="show_memories(obj)"

Comment: another option is get the updated contactList array from your service when you call changeAlertState()

Comment: the issue is more related to the sendChangeState function. But don't you think as contactList is an object it can be a problem ?

Comment: if you are iterating contactList it must be an array and you have to get contact list as an array

Comment: For changing the toBeAlerted you have to update your contactList array

Comment: Ok I see. There 's a custom pipe `separator`in the ngFor

Comment: Actually went back to [color] for dynamic changes, it works.